# No value to update but still an TABLE UPDATE Operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization

I see this type of code a lot in my databases

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sample WHERE ID=@id)
BEGIN    
UPDATE sample SET name='cat' WHERE id=@id;   
END
```

So from my primary analysis it does 2 scan in the `sample` table which is quiet unnecessary , so when analysed

Assumption 1: if id exists

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sample WHERE ID=4)
BEGIN    
UPDATE sample SET name='cat' WHERE id=4;
END
--with out if clause
UPDATE sample SET name='cat' WHERE id=4;
```

When checking the query plan I get this.
[image: Assumption 1]

in which an extra scan is done for the `IF` clause which is 11% of the  batch

Assumption 2: if id not exits

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sample WHERE ID=30)
BEGIN    
UPDATE sample SET name='cat' WHERE id=30;
END
--with out if clause
UPDATE sample SET name='cat' WHERE id=30;
```

[image: Assumption 2]
here even though there is nothing to update sql server used the `UPDATE`operator 
Now this makes the first query a bit efficient in which it skips the update operation ,
So why sql server used the `TABLE UPDATE`operator even if there's nothing to update.
which query is efficient?
In my case most of the time the id will exist in my database so I opted the second method
but is there any work around for this?

```
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.1" Build="10.0.1600.22" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
  <Batch>
  <Statements>
    <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" StatementSubTreeCost="0.00330166" StatementText="IF exists ( SELECT 1 FROM sample where id=30)&#xD;" StatementType="COND WITH QUERY" QueryHash="0xC6C2301D8BFF33B0" QueryPlanHash="0xEE6BE951A74F117D">
      <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="false" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
      <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" CachedPlanSize="8" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="104">
        <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="1E-07" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00330166">
          <OutputList>
            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
          </OutputList>
          <ComputeScalar>
            <DefinedValues>
              <DefinedValue>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CASE WHEN [Expr1006] THEN (1) ELSE (0) END">
                  <IF>
                    <Condition>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Condition>
                    <Then>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Const ConstValue="(1)" />
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Then>
                    <Else>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Else>
                  </IF>
                </ScalarOperator>
              </DefinedValue>
            </DefinedValues>
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="4.18E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Left Semi Join" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Nested Loops" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00330156">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <NestedLoops Optimized="false">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <ProbeColumn>
                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1006" />
                </ProbeColumn>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="1.157E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Constant Scan" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Constant Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.157E-06">
                  <OutputList />
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <ConstantScan />
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="11" EstimateCPU="0.0001669" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Table Scan" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032919" TableCardinality="9">
                  <OutputList />
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <TableScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                    <DefinedValues />
                    <Object Database="[test]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sample]" IndexKind="Heap" />
                    <Predicate>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[test].[dbo].[sample].[id]=(30)">
                        <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Identifier>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[test]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sample]" Column="id" />
                            </Identifier>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Const ConstValue="(30)" />
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Compare>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Predicate>
                  </TableScan>
                </RelOp>
              </NestedLoops>
            </RelOp>
          </ComputeScalar>
        </RelOp>
      </QueryPlan>
    </StmtSimple>
  </Statements>
</Batch>
<Batch>
  <Statements>
    <StmtSimple StatementCompId="2" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="2" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0132947" StatementText="UPDATE [sample] set [name] = @1  WHERE [id]=@2" StatementType="UPDATE" QueryHash="0x93FCD1485182723F" QueryPlanHash="0x71BB5E8A8AF43EF8">
      <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="false" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
      <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="0" CachedPlanSize="16" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="120">
        <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="1E-06" EstimateIO="0.01" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Update" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Update" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0132947">
          <OutputList />
          <RunTimeInformation>
            <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
          </RunTimeInformation>
          <Update DMLRequestSort="false">
            <Object Database="[test]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sample]" IndexKind="Heap" />
            <SetPredicate>
              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[test].[dbo].[sample].[name] = [Expr1004]">
                <ScalarExpressionList>
                  <ScalarOperator>
                    <MultipleAssign>
                      <Assign>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[test]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sample]" Column="name" />
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Identifier>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                          </Identifier>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </Assign>
                    </MultipleAssign>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </ScalarExpressionList>
              </ScalarOperator>
            </SetPredicate>
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="24" EstimateCPU="1E-07" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Compute Scalar" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Compute Scalar" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00329372">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
              </OutputList>
              <ComputeScalar>
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(10),[@1],0)">
                      <Identifier>
                        <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1011">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Convert DataType="varchar" Length="10" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="@1" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Convert>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </ColumnReference>
                      </Identifier>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="15" EstimateCPU="1E-07" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Top" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Top" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00329362">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <Top RowCount="true" IsPercent="false" WithTies="false">
                    <TopExpression>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(0)">
                        <Const ConstValue="(0)" />
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </TopExpression>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="19" EstimateCPU="8.84E-05" EstimateIO="0.0032035" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Table Scan" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032919" TableCardinality="9">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <RunTimeInformation>
                        <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                      </RunTimeInformation>
                      <TableScan Ordered="true" ForcedIndex="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Bmk1000" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[test]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sample]" IndexKind="Heap" />
                        <Predicate>
                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[test].[dbo].[sample].[id]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[@2],0)">
                            <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[test]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[sample]" Column="id" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="ConstExpr1010">
                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                      <Convert DataType="int" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                          <Identifier>
                                            <ColumnReference Column="@2" />
                                          </Identifier>
                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                      </Convert>
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                  </ColumnReference>
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Predicate>
                      </TableScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Top>
                </RelOp>
              </ComputeScalar>
            </RelOp>
          </Update>
        </RelOp>
        <ParameterList>
          <ColumnReference Column="@1" ParameterCompiledValue="'bijude 1 '" ParameterRuntimeValue="'bijude 1 '" />
          <ColumnReference Column="@2" ParameterCompiledValue="(4)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(30)" />
        </ParameterList>
      </QueryPlan>
    </StmtSimple>
  </Statements>
</Batch>
```

Comment: Just use `UPDATE sample SET name='cat' WHERE id=@id;` - if no rows are found to update nothing will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

- Your plans show that the only option for looking up a scalar `id` in the table is a scan. This clearly indicates a missing index.
- Your code is incorrect under concurrency.
- Query plans have to work for *any* parameter value.

To give an analogy, consider this example in a non-SQL language:

```
int x;
void f(int i)
{
 if (i != 1)
  x++;
}
```

You are asking the equivalent of "when I'm calling the function with the value `1`, why did the compiler generate the code for `x++`, even though is not executed?"

You are approaching this from a completely wrong angle, trying to second guess optimizer choices without understanding how queries are executed. Read:

- [Understanding how SQL Server executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/)
- [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/)

Comment: Agree with the optimizer will generate a general plan , but why this much cost? And I did liked that analogy. Oops I came to conclusion with out proper understanding , need to go back and  try hard.

Comment: If you want to understand why the cost is 75%, post the actual plan (.sqlplan XML) not a picture. It contains information that can explain the cost. You can also inspect the XML yourself, or use a better plan viewer like [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view).